# issue with posting to WCF REST service

Tags: wcf, rest, post

I created a REST service using WCF. It has 2 operations; one has [WebGet] applied to it and works fine both on localhost and on my production server.

But, the other operation that has the following attribute applied to it works the only localhost, not on the production server. Can anybody tell me what could be wrong here?

The attribute in question is:

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
           BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
           ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
           RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
           UriTemplate = "CreateUser")]
```

The error that I am getting is a bad request (400). The JSON request sent is the same for both localhost and prod server. It also has content type set to `application/json`.

Comment: This looks very similar to this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/911859/wcf-rest-post-xml-the-remote-server-returned-an-error-400-bad-request If it does not help post more details

Comment: The URL that you gave has a similar problem but the data exchange format is XML and that guy had a wrong namespace in the xml request that he was sending to the service. My service consumes JSON data and as such namespace fix suggested there won't work for me ... if you need any more details I'll be glad to give you ...

Comment: Do you call it with content type "application/json"