# Using WCF REST with POST

Tags: wcf, json, post

I have an WCF service which is working mostly with GET but one contract should work with POST.
I can't get it working - it returns "405 Method Not Allowed" all the time.

The service should recieve JSON and return a JSON.

I guess it something with the configuration. Here is my web.config file:

```
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>

<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"
  multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
<standardEndpoints>
  <webHttpEndpoint>
     <standardEndpoint name="" helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="false" defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Json" />
  </webHttpEndpoint>
</standardEndpoints>
```

and the service itself

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "LoginUser", BodyStyle=WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    public int Login(string user, string password)
```

{
....
}

Any ideas? Help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/911859/wcf-rest-post-xml-the-remote-server-returned-an-error-400-bad-request and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41155/wcf-service-returning-method-not-allowed

Comment: sadly it's not a duplicate :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you're really making a POST. Because your code seems valid.

Try it by creating a new html-file containing something like:

```
<form action="http://{Address to your service}/Service.svc/LoginUser" method="POST">
    <input type="submit" value="Fire away!" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out my comments for the duplicates but it boils down to making sure you have the correct verb supplied in your operation contract.  Here is an example:

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://www.test.com/youruri")]
public interface ISomeService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST")]
    string SomeMethod();
}
```

Comment: It seems all is ok. changed the "BodyStyle" to Bare - and get a server error. So I guess it's not it :)

Comment: Okay, my example was a little muddied, forget about the RequestFormat stuff, just make sure the Method = "POST" is in there.

Comment: Yes. It's all there... That's the strange part. Maybe it's a web.config problem?

Comment: Thanks. I couldn't find anything useful for the problem. I think it's something with the WCF and the HTTP itself.

Comment: Yeah, I think you are right.  I dug around for about an hour or so and nothing really points out definitively what the problem is.  A colleague of mine at work just passed the WCF exam for MCSD so I'll ask him tomorrow if you still haven't found the answer then.  Good luck!