# POST data to WCF Service from WP7

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-phone-7

I am working on a WP7 application. If an error happens, I want to log the error back to my server. To handle this, I have created a WCF service operation. I want this operation to be REST ful so that I can later use it with iPhone and Android apps. Because I'm writing information to the database, I thought the POST method would be best. For this reason, I'm using WebInvoke. To do this, I'm using the following code:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/LogError/{message}/{stackTrace}", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
public void LogError(string message, string stackTrace)
{
  // Write info to the database
}
```

From my WP7 app, I want to call this operaiton via a WebClient. My question is, how do I do that? I don't understand how to call the LogError operation and pass along the required data via the WebClient.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: One thing I would add is be careful about using your users 3G connection for posting back analytics info like this.  If possible try to cache the error information and only send it when you have a WiFi or ethernet connection. You can use NetworkInterface.NetworkInterfaceType to determine which type of connection you have (although be careful because accessing this property is a blocking call).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something along the lines:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://serveraddress/LogError/{message}/{stackTrace}");
```

If you would want to send additional information later on, you can do so with:

```
request.Method = "POST";
request.BeginGetRequestStream(new AsyncCallback(ExecuteAction), request);
```

And have a callback:

```
void ExecuteAction(IAsyncResult result)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)result.AsyncState;
    using (Stream s = request.EndGetRequestStream(result))
    {
        s.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
    }
}
```

If there is a specific string response from the service, you might as well include the data in the WebClient and use [DownloadStringAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadstringasync%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) to get the response data.

Answer (score 2):

If I am getting your Service method correctly, that method is not a POST method. You can just call that with a WebClient

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient()
Uri uri = new Uri("http://yourUri/LogError/ABC/XYZ"); //ABC is your message and XYZ is your stacktrace string.
wc.DownloadStringAsync(uri);
```

Or if you are thinking about real HTTP 'POST' then below might help.
You can use HttpWebRequest to do a POST on to any service which is accepting POST

This link may be helpful - [WCF REST POST XML - The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/911859/wcf-rest-post-xml-the-remote-server-returned-an-error-400-bad-request)

Answer (score 1):

For starters, I found a website that should help you get started with calling the service from WP7.

Try [this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/raj1979/5280/Default.aspx) and let me know what you think

Comment: Thanks for providing the link. Unfortunately that wasn't really what I was looking for. It just seems like there should be an easy way to do a POST to a WCF service via the WebClient. I have to be overlooking something. Thank you for trying though.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this post http://blog.ike.to/2011/02/02/wp7-application-crash-reporter/

It sounds like it will pretty much do what you need already, although you might want to tweak it to suit your own service interface.